# How do I supply a private passphrase when using a certificate in an HTTP request?

Tags: perl

I have a private certificate that I use to authenticate with an external webserver.  I want to automate downloading the webpage, but it requires my private key passphrase whenever it makes a request.  Is there a way to provide this key through the script somehow (either in an environment variable or otherwise)?  One small caveat: this needs to run on a Windows machine, so I cannot use the Expect module.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $output_doc = $ARGV[0];
my $url = $ARGV[1];
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://1.2.3.4:3128';
$ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = "Net::SSL";
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0; 
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = 'test_cert/cert.pem';
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE} = 'test_cert/private.key';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "$url");
my $response = $ua->request($req);

open OUT, ">$output_doc";
print OUT $response->as_string;
close OUT;
```

So far it works properly.  It pulls down the webpage I provide in the second argument, but for each page I have to type my PEM passphrase.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

[Remove the passphrase from the key.](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html)

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -out private-nopass.key
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  We want to keep the key with the password on it though.

Comment: If the key's password is stored plaintext in a script, there's not really a point in having the password in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot supply passphrase for LWP::UserAgent, just **remove** it **from** certificate **key**.

You may try the following:

```
...
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "$url"); 

$IO::Socket::SSL::GLOBAL_CONTEXT_ARGS->{SSL_passwd_cb} = sub { 
  # get passphrase
  return $passphrase 
};

my $response = $ua->request($req);
...
```

---

Optionally you may consider to use:

```
# Client PKCS12 cert support 
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE}     = 'certs/pkcs12.pkcs12'; 
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'PKCS12_PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating the key in the PKCS12 format.

```
# Client PKCS12 cert support
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE}     = 'certs/pkcs12.pkcs12';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'PKCS12_PASSWORD';
```

This worked without a problem.

Comment: Which is exactly what I suggested you in my original answer and which you just coppied. Well, but that is not an answer to the question you posted, correct?

Comment: @stackoverflow: Actually, [you seem to have been the one who copied his answer into yours](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10214022/revisions). The OP posted this before you edited your answer. He couldn't possibly have copied it from you, unless you know something that we don't. Would you care to elaborate on this?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Incorrect - As moderator you should see my another answer that was deleted and see date and time of that post. Got it?

Comment: @stackoverflow: Your answer has been deleted for quite long. There's no telling the OP could have seen and used it before it was deleted.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - At least you see I am NOT a copy-cat. He saw it and that's why it is EXACT copy of that, not similar, but IDENTICAL (each character). Anyway...